# Node.js and PHP

Tags: php, node.js

I'm having a hard time figuring this out. I'm building a game and I want the game to be coded with Node.js (partly for learning and partly cause it seems right). But the game will also have a community and other stuff that will be in PHP.

So my question is. How do I talk to Node.js with PHP? Let' say that a user signs in and goes to the actual game (which is real time between to players), how do I give the user information to Node.js?

Or should I simply code everything with Node.js? I just want to be pushed in the right direction, what is the best way?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you've tried, but since you question is pretty broad, try starting here: http://bergie.iki.fi/blog/dnode-make_php_and_node-js_talk_to_each_other/

Comment: I should also say, the "best" way is totally up to you and your skill level. Some would argue that the "best" way to approach a project is to play to your strengths. If Node.js isn't your strength then don't feel forced to use that because it might "feel" right. On the other hand, if you have some anecdotal or real evidence that Node.js or any other technology is best suited for your application then the "best" way may be the path which you know little about.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I haven't tried anything yet really. I'm pretty new to Node.js but far more experienced with PHP. The reason why I'm doing this in the first place is for learning purposes, that's why I'm working with Node.js. Also Node.js seems to be the perfect fit when working with real time applications.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using JooDee, a node webserver which allows you to embed serverside javascript in your web pages.  If you are familiar with Node and PHP/ASP, it is a breeze to create pages.  Here's a sample of what a page looks like below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<:  //server side code in here
    var os = require('os');
    var hostname = os.hostname();
:>
<body>
    <div>Your hostname is <::hostname:></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Using JooDee also lets you expose server javascript vars to the client with no effort by attaching attributes to the 'Client' object server side, and accessing the generated 'Client' object in your client side javascript.

https://github.com/BigIroh/JooDee